# Cannot remove directory in AIX

Tags: aix, system-administration

I want to ask why I can't remove a directory inside my AIX named `Suc`? I have tried many ways to remove it but still can't. Can anyone help?

I have tried the commands : `rmdir` , `rmdir -p` ,`rmdir -f` , `rm -rf`

> rmdir: 0653-609 Cannot remove Suc.
>   A file or directory in the path name does not exist.

Comment: It may be because `Suc` doesn't exist in the current path, but that's just a wild guess. Could you post the *full command* you are using? With path and everything?

Comment: i used rmdir Suc, rmdir -p Suc, rmdir -r -f Suc.

Comment: i used ls -l but it show folder Suc. when i tried to remove it says : rmdir: 0653-609 Cannot remove Suc. A file or directory in the path name does not exist.

Comment: Maybe there is a non-printable character inside the name of this directory? Maybe a blank space? If there is no other file/dir in this path that starts with `Suc`, you could try `rm -r Suc*`.

Comment: It might have something to do with access-rights. Examine the output of this command: `X="$(realpath Suc)"; ( echo "$X"; while X="$(dirname "$X")"; [ $X '!=' '/' ]; do echo "$X"; done ) |  xargs ls -ld`

Comment: now able to delete. I remove using inode number (find . -inum 782263 -exec rm -i {} \;)

Thanks all for your support